# Package cairo not found in pakg-config search path

Tags: terminal, npm-install

[image]

sachin@sachin-Inspiron-15-3567:~/Desktop/Projects/api.ohphish.com$ npm install
npm WARN read-shrinkwrap This version of npm is compatible with lockfileVersion@1, but npm-shrinkwrap.json was generated for lockfileVersion@0. I'll try to do my best with it!
npm WARN read-shrinkwrap This version of npm is compatible with lockfileVersion@1, but npm-shrinkwrap.json was generated for lockfileVersion@0. I'll try to do my best with it!
npm WARN read-shrinkwrap This version of npm is compatible with lockfileVersion@1, but npm-shrinkwrap.json was generated for lockfileVersion@0. I'll try to do my best with it!
npm WARN read-shrinkwrap This version of npm is compatible with lockfileVersion@1, but npm-shrinkwrap.json was generated for lockfileVersion@0. I'll try to do my best with it!

> canvas@1.6.13 install /home/sachin/Desktop/Projects/api.ohphish.com/node_modules/chartjs-node/node_modules/canvas
> node-gyp rebuild

Package cairo was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `cairo.pc' to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable No package 'cairo' found gyp: Call to './util/has_lib.sh freetype' returned exit status 0 while in binding.gyp. while trying to load binding.gyp gyp ERR! configure error  gyp ERR! stack Error:` gyp` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onCpExit (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/configure.js:351:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:315:20)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:277:12)
gyp ERR! System Linux 5.4.0-42-generic
gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /home/sachin/Desktop/Projects/api.ohphish.com/node_modules/chartjs-node/node_modules/canvas
gyp ERR! node -v v14.15.4
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v5.1.0
gyp ERR! not ok
npm WARN chartjs-node@1.7.1 requires a peer of chart.js@<=2.7.* but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@2.3.1 (node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@2.3.1: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! canvas@1.6.13 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the canvas@1.6.13 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

Answer (score 1):

I installed dev dependencies by issueing command.

```
sudo apt-get install libcairo2-dev libjpeg-dev libgif-dev build-essential
```